# What is the difference between the intergrated perc controller and the addon perc controller on a Dell 610

Tags: dell, perc6

I'm looking at the Dell 610. It comes with a PERC 6/I integrated controller card, whats the difference between this and the available add on card which is a PERC6E Raid Controller ?

My goal is to have disk mirroring.

Cheers,

MrT

Answer (score 1):

PERC 6/i is an internal disk controller.  The 6E is an external controller for use in attaching an external disk tray.  If your goal is simply to mirror internal disks, you'll want to go with the 6/i.